# displaying 2 lement in same div vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How to display the date time picker and

element in the same time?
i got problem when I run the program date time picker doesn't show. just "lala" in the

element.

```
    <div id="app">
        <v-date-picker mode="dateTime" v-model='date'/>
        <p>lala</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar"></script>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                date: new Date(),                 // settiing default hari yg terpilih waktu pas datepicker ke load hari $ waktu skrng
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate v-date-picker and the p tag in two separate divs.

```html
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <v-date-picker mode="dateTime" v-model="date" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>{{date}}</p>
      <p>lala</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```